# Grails over Groovy: What does it offer?

Tags: java, web-applications, grails, groovy

I would like to know what are the advantages and disadvantages of using Grails over pure vanilla Groovy installation.

What functionalities does Grails bring to Groovy as a framework?

-What does it offer? Which functionalities and peculiarities does it bring? 
   -What does it take away?
   -What does it enforce on the developer?
   -What liberties does it bring to the developer?

Finally,

-Why use Grails over pure Groovy? What would be the reasons?

-What do you need to give up to incorporate Grails for production? What kind of control do you let go? What kind of performance is jeopardised?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails is basically groovy + spring mvc + an ORM (gorm) + scaffolding scripts + the "convention over configuration" attitude of rails, etc.

So if you didn't need an orm (say, your web app was backed by a rest or soap api), using a servlet app written with groovy, or a spring mvc app with groovy, would be a reasonable choice.

Like Rails, Grails seems to be what I call "Strongly Grained". If you do things the Grails way, development is easy (and generally quite fast). The framework tends to have a preferred way of doing most things. On the other hand, if you need to go against the grain, you'll have a comparably rough time of it.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy is a general purpose language that you can use to write almost any kind of software. Grails is a web framework that is used to develop web applications using the Groovy language. So I suppose you could say that Grails greatly simplifies developing web applications using Groovy.